# ssh: Could not resolve hostname. Name or service not known

Tags: hadoop, ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosts

I'm trying to set up hadoop on my amazon instances, on a 2 node cluster. Each instance has a public dns, which I use reference them. So in the /etc/hosts files on both machines I append lines like this:

```
{public dns of 1st instance} node1
{public dns of 2st instance} node2
```

I'm also able to ssh into each instance from the other by simply doing:

```
ssh {public dns of the other instance}
```

In the the hadoop/conf/slaves on the first instance file I have:

```
localhost
node2
```

When I start the script bin/start-dfs.sh
It's able to start the namenode, datanode, and secondary namenode on the master, but it says:

```
node2: ssh: Could not resolve hostname node2: Name or service not known
```

The same it printed out if I try:

```
ssh node2
```

I guess the question is how do I tell it to associate node2 with the public dns of the second instance. Is it not enough to append the

```
{public dns of 2st instance} node2
```

line to the /etc/hosts file?
Do I have to reboot the instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/hosts` kind of act like a local DNS, when you don't have real DNS associated with an IP address.

Do you really need a `{public dns of 1st instance} node1` mapping if you can use {public dns of 1st instance} directly in the slave and master files?

Moreover, it's better to use the private IP addresses of amazon instances instead of using the public IP addresses. You can do a `ifconfig` in the terminal of each instances and determine their private IP addresses if any. They will probably basically will start with 10.x.x.x/172.x.x.x/192.x.x.x? You can probably then map those instead in /etc/hosts in each of the amazon instances.

So, your /etc/hosts in each machine should look something like -

Machine-1:

```
{IP_address_1st_instance} node1
{IP_address_2st_instance} node2
```

Machine-2:

```
{IP_address_1st_instance} node1
{IP_address_2st_instance} node2
```

And, this is so that the Amazon instances(machines) can resolve each other, if you are anyhow planning to map them.

Comment: There would no problem with using public dns, directly in the masters and slave files. As for using the private ip, I had just replaced the public dns with the corresponding private ip in the /etc/hosts file, before I saw your answer, but it gave me the same error.

Comment: but I did use ip-10.x.x.x, rather than 10.x.x.x, could that have been the issue?

Comment: I can ssh using the private ip if i do ssh ip-10.x.x.x., but not ssh 10.x.x.x

Comment: "but I did use ip-10.x.x.x, rather than 10.x.x.x" - I didn't get you?

Comment: The aws console tells you the private ip but with "ip-" infront of the address

Comment: Can you ping 10.x.x.x?

Comment: Did you map the private ip address of both in each of the machines in /etc/hosts? i.e. your both '{IP_address_1st_instance} node1' and '{IP_address_2st_instance} node2' mapping should go in every machine's /etc/hosts

Comment: I can't ping "10.x.x.x", but I can ping "ip-10.x.x.x"

Comment: I was able to start everything when i replaced the "node1" and "node2" with the actual ips, but I'm having a hadoop problem now, it tells me the connection to localhost is refused, even though I can do a passphraseless ssh into localhost

Comment: do you have localhost mapped to 127.0.0.1 and nothing else in the /etc/hosts?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35100/discussion-between-jtherocker-and-amre)

Comment: My work network let me open the chat page, but the I just rmemebered, i had forgotten to staart mapreduce when I did the example. Thanks for your help, putting the ip worked.

Comment: Glad that it woreked!