# Unknown hostname error - Raspbian

Tags: linux, networking, ip, raspberry-pi3, gnome-terminal

I have a windows server running inside a VM and trying to access it from a `raspberry pi 3` which is configured to have access to the VM network.

Problem is when I `ping` the server with its' IP it responds but when I do it with the name (in my case it's `nlux807`) it throws `Unknown Hostname nlux807`
How can I resolve it?

I am quite new to Raspbian. Any handy tip will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the windows server registering the hostname to a DNS service? What is the type of VM you are running them? Generally, what is the network setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Windows server has a static IP, you can edit the file ***/etc/hosts*** on the Raspberry Pi device and add the following line:

`192.168.0.99  nlux807   # Actually the IP address of the Windows server`

That will make `ping nlux807` work.

This is similar to [ssh-could-not-resolve-hostname-name-or-service-not-known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134231/ssh-could-not-resolve-hostname-name-or-service-not-known?rq=1).

Comment: Excellent! Worked like a charm :) Thanks a ton @Quirysse

Comment: The issue is probably 90% similar but I don't think it is a direct duplicate.